# Angular2 is not recognizing an object within an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
clusters = [
    {
        latitude: 51.521024,
        longitude: 5.134832,
        icon: '/img/map/marker-cluster-jungalow.png',
        draggable: true,
        clusterAvailibilty: {
            latitude: 51.521424544801285,
            longitude: 5.133759116394003
        }
    },
    {
        latitude: 51.52444186907029,
        longitude: 5.137406920654257,
        icon: '/img/map/marker-cluster-jungalow.png',
        draggable: true,
        clusterAvailibilty: {
            latitude: 51.521424544801285,
            longitude: 5.133759116394003
        }
    }
]
```

Now I want to loop trough the clusters.clusterAvailibilty like this:

```
<sebm-google-map-overlay-view 
  *ngFor="let available of clusters.clusterAvailibilty"
  [latitude]="available.latitude" [longitude]="available.longitude" 
  [objectId]="kind.count"
  [class]="'availability'">
</sebm-google-map-overlay-view>
```

But it is not showing anything could someone help me out on this>

Comment: How do you let this work? https://plnkr.co/edit/uYpi17?p=preview

Comment: The "duplicate" flagging is wrong here, the asker is not trying to iterate an object !

Comment: The answer is to simply iterate over "clusters", not `clusters.clusterAvailability`: `<sebm-google-map-overlay-view 
  *ngFor="let available of clusters"
  [latitude]="available.clusterAvailability.latitude" [longitude]="available.clusterAvailability.longitude" 
  [objectId]="kind.count"
  [class]="'availability'">
</sebm-google-map-overlay-view>`